# React Typescript Generic Type Overloading (e.g. useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, overloading

I am attempting to create an overloaded function that will write to and from session storage instead of the standard state. I'd like it to be overloadable in the instances where I only provide a type and not an initial value. Exactly like what `useState` does in react.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
export function useSessionState<S = undefined>(initialState?: S): [S, (state: S) => void];
export function useSessionState<S>(initialState: S): [S, (state: S) => void] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<S>()

  // Unimportant: Do something to load to and from session storage.

  return [state, (value) => {

  }]
}
```

When I try to consume this type I only ever get the result type of one of the overloads.

```js
// Variable 'state' is a string as expected.
const [state, setState] = useSessionState("some_initial_value")

// Variable 'undefinedState' is also a string, but it should be undefined since no 'initialState' was provided.
const [undefinedState, setUndefinedState] = useSessionState<string>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know the answer myself, so I started reading and experimenting. My attempts come pretty close, but I see the following flaws:

- Both attempts show `initialState` as being of type `S` instead of `S | undefined`, which means you'd strugle to implement this function without a cast.
- The generated `.d.ts` of the first solution and the second solution are different. I believe the `.d.ts` of the first attempt more closely resembles the official `useState` definition.
- Even though you didn't mention it:

  - `initialState` can be a value or a function, which is only the case in the second attempt.
  - The `setState` function should probably have a parameter of type `S | undefined`, rather than `S`.

Hopefully there is a better solution...
If only the [actual implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L91) was written in Typescript.

## Attempt 1: [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwMpQIZTQHgwD4AKGMGWbAGy1zQC5EMBKJgbQwBpESUc8TVogC8RRADc4MACYBdANwAoUJFgJk6OnkKjkYGWmDk0M0m0SdEAH32HjYUzz4DGzFqPFTZileGjwSKiYrroidkYmZmQUVLSuAPxCFlZoAB54BigRDqaICTlRNsyIQs789MmektLyiADeSoiIUAAWAE5wAO6Ijj0Aou2d7SQABgBycFCIMAC2AA7UaLNoYHgyiNgGvVOa5ADmiAAk9eSUMDTaaAC+oyzK10pKEAj8lhV4AIw86FBXn3I9MErvh+O0DqQAERnOIANRoIDQkPuiAA9KjEGCDs9XtN2B80AAmH5oP6uQmA8LA1wkaGxC7UeHURHIhRojFYsD7HFgN741wAZhJZPoAspmhC9FBUHBXPMbPRhUcG1snO5L15eIJABZhVdteLqfQSCjFeB7FEgA)

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S): [S, (state: S) => void];
function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, (state: S) => void];
function useState<S = undefined>(initialState?: S): [S extends undefined ? undefined | S : S, (state: S) => void] {
  throw new Error(`Not implemented and not using ${initialState}`);
}

const [state1, setState1] = useState<string>("initialValue"); // string
const [state2, setState2] = useState("initialValue"); // string
const [state3, setState3] = useState<string>(); // undefined | string
const [state4, setState4] = useState(); // undefined
```

The `.d.ts` that is generated on the playground:

```
declare function useState<S>(initialState: S): [S, (state: S) => void];
declare function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, (state: S) => void];
```

## Attempt 2: Without conditional types

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZzAQ2AYwBYB4AqA+KAXigAoA3ZAGwFcIAuKHASiILIHs4ATAbgCg+AM2oA7NMDjsRUagggBlYKghZ5RGSK4RBcERC54STBgG01AHw1adergBpYiFOmwWr23frwBdfsLESUjJyisqqhrpwElShwBAA-AxuJEasUPJMxlBmDvBIqJjhvkKi4pLSsgpKceEkkdGUsQlJUJYpLIQEGVk5jvkuRVAA3nxQY1DAGABO7ADuUHrzAKJTM1MkAAYAcuzAUHAAtmCUEAcQInFcUMiaC7vBugDmUAAkQ-VwMdUQAL4bTPwfqM+GgpAg9iZwcoAIwOOTAJrQ7zqSpNLDgqZPQwAIg+VAAalRaNiAVAAPRkqAYp4gsEQqFxABMcIgCO+jORxFR3xIuJEUU+lEJNAgJJ45Mp1JEj1pInB2QZEAAzCy2colZzglUwlLHoZSRT3DZ9K0qcBMdLZfLId8ACyqpq2zXc5RGcWG0TWTxcIA)

```
type Dispatch<T> = (value: T) => void;

function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<S | undefined>];
function useState<S>(initialState?: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>];
function useState<S>(initialState?: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>] {
    throw new Error(`Not implemented and not using ${initialState}`);
}
 
const [state1, setState1] = useState<string>("initialValue"); // string
const [state2, setState2] = useState("initialValue"); // string
const [state3, setState3] = useState<string>(); // undefined | string
const [state4, setState4] = useState(); // undefined
```

The `.d.ts` that is generated on the playground:

```
declare function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<S | undefined>];
declare function useState<S>(initialState?: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<S>];
```

Comment: Edited to add the 2nd attempt.